# How to turn a digital output off after 2 seconds using a timer

Tags: timer, interrupt, avr, atmega

I have an Atmega328p and want to turn on a digital output with a button press, then have it turn off automatically after 2 seconds.

I know how to use a hardware interrupt for the button, but how do I set up a timer interrupt to automatically turn the digital output back off?

---

UPDATE:

I was able to figure it out.  Here's my solution (only showing the pertinent functions):

```c
static inline void initTimer1(void) {

    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);  // CTC Mode, immediate
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10) | (1 << CS12);  // Clock speed: 16 MHz / 1024, ~= 15.6 ticks per ms

}

void set_valve_on_time(uint16_t on_time) {

    OCR1A = on_time;  // set output compare register for valve on time

}

void open_valve(uint8_t state) {

    if (state > 0) {
        PORTD |= (1 << PIND6);  //turn on PD6, open valve
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PIND7);  //turn off PD7, turn off close valve in case it was on
        if (state == 2) {
            TCNT1 = 0;
            TIFR1 |= (1 << OCF1A);  // clear output compare match flag
            TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);  // enable output compare interrupt
        }
    }
    else {
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PIND6);  //turn off PD6, stop opening valve
    }   

}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {

    TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << OCIE1A);  // disable output compare interrupt
    open_valve(0);  //turn off close valve output

}
```

The open_valve function is called by a button press (not shown).  The hardest time I had was figuring out that I needed  `TIFR1 |= (1 << OCF1A)`  for it to work correctly.  I still don't quite understand why, because I thought the ISR was supposed to do this automatically.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Just researching at the moment.  Seems like I'd need to do some sort of timer compare, and enable the timer interrupt when button pushed, and disable interrupt after timer is met.

Comment: Use one of the timers of the Atmega and switch off its output in the timer interrupt function. The timer can be started in the main loop. So you should look for timers and timer interrupts. Everything is well documented in the Atmega manual.

Answer (score 0):

you have to roughly follow these steps:

- on your button handling routine set up the timer with the folling properties:

  - best use 16bit timer in CTC mode (if you have free timers available)
  - set the prescaler so that the timer otherflows a bit slower than your compare value: 
    for 2sec and 10MHz CPU frequency i would run it on the 1/1024 prescaler, so a overflow would occure on (10.000.000/1024/65536) -> 1 overflow per ~6.7s (with 265 it would overflow more often than once per 2s)
  - set the ctc top value (see description of your selected mode - the specific register varies) to a value that is reached after 2s : 10.000.000/1024 * 2s --> 19531
- implement the ISR (see which would be the correct one in the selected CTC mode) the and activate the Interupt in the mask register

  - in the ISR set your output, and stop the timer
- Bonus: setup the timer that it uses the output compare pins to deactivate the output
  Then no ISR is required at all, just set the Compare Output Mode to 'clear on Match'

If you do not have a free 16bit timer, i would suggest to use 1 timer in CTC mode to generate a (10) millisecond timebase, and implement the time-counting logic in this ms-event handling.